# Setting a deployment lock for Kubernetes namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, locking, gitlab, bitbucket-pipelines

I would like to perform a system test using multiple services. During test I would like to prevent deployments from happening for a given namespace in order to have stable environment. Is it possible to have such lock?

My use case is CI/CD flow:

I will have bitbucket / gitlab pipeline, deploy a service. Then I want to perform system tests among multiple services inside a namespace. During this system test I want to prevent deployments in order to make tests more stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) with a [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) limited to a single namespace.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: user
  namespace: mynamespace

---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: user-full-access
  namespace: mynamespace
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
- apiGroups: ["batch"]
  resources:
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  verbs: ["*"]

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: mynamespace-user-view
  namespace: mynamespace
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: user
  namespace: mynamespace
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: user-full-access
```

Comment: And how I can set an release such lock programmatically?

Comment: The easy way is to call `kubectl delete rolebinding <name>` you can also call the kubeapi service directly if you'd like to. There are client libraries in a few programing languages

Comment: Ok, that sounds promising. I've updated my question. I will be using pipelines. So before the test I will need to acquire the `lock` and after finishing the `lock` needs to be released